# tracking clicks on anchor tel links

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, anchor, tel

I am embedding anchor links on mobile smart phone browsers using the tel anchor link.

```
<a href='tel:xxx-yyy-zzzz'>xxx-yyy-zzzz</a>
```

My understanding is that the smart phone intercepts the link and allows the user to directly call.

How can i track the user click on this link?

use a 302 redirect?

Answer (score 1):

The only answer is to use a redirect, sorry.

```
<a href="redirect.php?number=123-456-798">Call Us</a>
```

Then, on redirect.php do a 302 redirect to the tel protocol for the number you have passed (or the default number).

Record the hits on redirect.php